# MySQL show processlist is truncated

Tags: mysql

`show processlist` truncates the `info` column. Os there a way to show the full query in the `info` column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

> If you do not use the FULL keyword, only the first 100 characters of each statement are shown in the Info field.